# Iterative ffill with median values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Appreciate any help on this.
Let's say I have the following df with two columns:

```
col1 col2 
NaN  NaN
11   100  
12   110
15   115
NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN
9    142
12   144
NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN
6    155
9    156
7    161
NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN
```

I'd like to forward fill and replace the Nan values with the median value of the preceding values. For example, the median of 11,12,15 in 'col1' is 12, therefore I need the Nan values to be filled with 12 until I get to the next non-Nan values in the column and continue iterating the same. See below the expected df:

```
col1 col2 
NaN   NaN
11    100  
12    110
15    115
12    110
12    110
12    110
9     142
12    144
10.5  143
10.5  143
10.5  143
6     155
9     156
7     161
7     156
7     156
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last two values in `col1` be `7` (the median) ?

Comment: Sorry - mistyped, correct should be 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
m1 = (df.col1.isna() != df.col1.isna().shift(1)).cumsum()
m2 = (df.col2.isna() != df.col2.isna().shift(1)).cumsum()

df["col1"] = df["col1"].fillna(
    df.groupby(m1)["col1"].transform("median").ffill()
)

df["col2"] = df["col2"].fillna(
    df.groupby(m2)["col2"].transform("median").ffill()
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    col1   col2
0    NaN    NaN
1   11.0  100.0
2   12.0  110.0
3   15.0  115.0
4   12.0  110.0
5   12.0  110.0
6   12.0  110.0
7    9.0  142.0
8   12.0  144.0
9   10.5  143.0
10  10.5  143.0
11  10.5  143.0
12   6.0  155.0
13   9.0  156.0
14   7.0  161.0
15   7.0  156.0
16   7.0  156.0
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, this seems to do the job!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if we fill null values like so:

- Fill with Median of last 3 non-null items.
- Fill with Median of last 2 non-null items.
- Front fill values.

We'll get what you're looking for.

```
out = (df.combine_first(df.rolling(4,3).median())
         .combine_first(df.rolling(3,2).median())
         .ffill())
print(out)
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2
0    NaN    NaN
1   11.0  100.0
2   12.0  110.0
3   15.0  115.0
4   12.0  110.0
5   12.0  110.0
6   12.0  110.0
7    9.0  142.0
8   12.0  144.0
9   10.5  143.0
10  10.5  143.0
11  10.5  143.0
12   6.0  155.0
13   9.0  156.0
14   7.0  161.0
15   7.0  156.0
16   7.0  156.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the length of the numerical values is not fixed and can vary.